# PHP Curl proxy option in Laravel Http Facade

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I am using Laravel's Http facade to make requests such as

```
Http::withHeaders(['user-agent' => 'My User agent'])->retry(3, 500)->get('https://example.com')->body();
```

And need to use proxy, which as per proxy provider's example should be set like this in case of PHP's curl

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'aaa');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'xxx:xxx');
```

Can these proxy options be somehow set with Laravel's Http class above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Http Facade is allowed you to use [guzzle options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#guzzle-options), and guzzle has [proxy option](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#proxy). So based on your code, you need to do like this:

```
Http::withHeaders(['user-agent' => 'My User agent'])
->withOptions(['proxy' => 'http://username:password@192.168.16.1:8080'])
->retry(3, 500)
->get('https://example.com')
->body();
```